# Using COUNT returns the same value when counting two different columns

Tags: count, syntax, google-bigquery

I am new to SQL and am using it for a school project and would like some help.

I have a table with multiple columns about a fictional company that provides a bike sharing service. One of the rows I am trying to count is called member_casual which returns a string with either casual or member, that reports whether a user is a member or not. The second column I am trying to count is a string column called rideable_type that reports what kind of bike it has. I want to create a table that returns the number of kinds of bikes per each kind or rider, casual or member.

Here is my code:

```sql
SELECT member_casual,
  COUNT(member_casual) AS member_type,
  COUNT(rideable_type) AS electric_classic
FROM `coursera-practice-356200.cycle_data.cycle_table1` 
GROUP BY member_casual
```

Here is my result:

| member_casual | member_type | electric_classic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| casual | 21416 | 21416 |
| . member. | . 94193. | . 94193. |

I know my code is flawed, but I do not know where it is flawed. I also do not know why I got the same number when I am counting two different columns (`member_casual` and `rideable_type`) which should be very different numbers.

I guess what I am asking is for assistance on where my code is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> I also do not know why I got the same number when I am counting two different columns (member_casual and rideable_type) which should be very different numbers.

The [`COUNT()` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#count) counts the number of non-null values in the column. There are no null values in your `member_casual` and `rideable_type` columns, so they share the same `COUNT()`, which effectively is just the number of rows in the grouping on `member_casual`.

> I want to create a table that returns the the number of **kind of bikes** per each **kind or rider**, casual or member.

You need to group on **both** of those fields then, to be able to get the counts of values in each within each other, like so:

```
SELECT
    member_casual,
    rideable_type,
    COUNT(rideable_type) AS bike_type_counts
FROM coursera-practice-356200.cycle_data.cycle_table1 
GROUP BY member_casual, rideable_type
```

Or to ypercube's point, if you what you're looking for is to count the unique number of `rideable_type`s in each `member_casual`, then you just need to add the `DISTINCT` keyword to the `COUNT()` function in your original query like so:

```
SELECT
    member_casual,
    COUNT(member_casual) AS member_type,
    COUNT(DISTINCT rideable_type) AS electric_classic
FROM coursera-practice-356200.cycle_data.cycle_table1 
GROUP BY member_casual
```

Comment: Maybe they just need to use DISTINCT in the count, eg `COUNT(DISTINCT rideable_type)`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes good point, updated. Depends on what OP's goal is. But you probably interpreted better.

Comment: No, either option maybe what they want. It's not clear.